# How do I attempt to start this problem or even begin to understand what its asking for?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

The question is,

"Suppose that a random variable X can take the value 1, 2, or any other positive integer. Is it possible that $P(X = i)$ = $c/i^2$ for some value of the constant $c$? Is it possible that $P(X = i)$ = $c/i$ for some value of $c$?"

So my initial thoughts are for any positive integer, are able to use it as a constant for c? And that some value of c can make the equation true?

I'm not asking for a direct answer just an easier way to comprehend the question so I can I solve it myself!

Comment: Suppose $P(X=i)=c/i^{2}$ for all positive integers $i.$ Is it possible that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X=i)=1,$ for some value of $c$? How about if $P(X=i)=c/i$ for all positive integers $i$?

Comment: So what your stating is that any value of c will result the summation to be 1?

Comment: No, I'm asking whether *there is* any value of $c$ which will result in the summation being $1.$

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember the law of total probability, namely that the probabilities of all outcomes adds up to $1$. Here the probabilities of
outcomes $1,2,3,\ldots,n,\ldots$ are $c,c/4,c/9,\ldots,c/n^2,\ldots$.

So is there a $c$ such that
$$c+\frac c4+\frac c9+\cdots+\frac c{n^2}+\cdots=1$$
and if so, what is it?

Comment: by your example I assume $c$ would have to equal 1?

Comment: or any value squared ?

Comment: @BartholomewAllen So, you believe that $1+\frac14+\frac19+\cdots=1$?

Comment: nope i just figured it out, c would have to equal $1/2$?

Comment: So you believe that $\frac12\left(1+\frac14+\frac19+\cdots\right)=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $ P(X=1)+P(X=2)+...+P(X=n)+...+ = 1$ and argue by contradiction.